# Force keyup event on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm loading a view of my own web into an iframe and into an input field loading some text with:

```
var f=$('#frameDemo');
f.contents().find("#filter_player").val(_this.attr('user-name'));
```

and is working fine.

In this input there is a function on keyup which is working if you do it manually but I want to force this keyup() event automatically.

I've tried with

```
f.contents().find("#filter_player").keyup();
```

and

```
f.contents().find("#filter_player").trigger("keyup");
```

But none is working. Any idea why it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use contentWindow for this purpose:

```
document.getElementById(‘iframeMsg’).contentWindow.$(‘a.first’).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Wow, it's working perfectly on this way

Thank you very much! :)